# How to convert Big5 encoded characters to Unicode in VC++

Tags: visual-c++, unicode, com, big5

I am trying to convert a Big5 encoded string received from another application to Unicode string and then display the Chinese characters in a browser. The dll which receives the Big5 character is a COM dll and is build using MBCS configuration. I cannot afford converting the dll to use Unicode Character Set configuration as it will be a big task for me.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: COM uses Unicode strings (via `BSTR`), so how is the COM DLL receiving a Big5-encoded string to begin with? Or is the DLL receiving the Big5 string through other internal means and then passes the string as Unicode (via `BSTR`?) to the hosting app?

Comment: My COM dll is receiving Big5 encoded string from another external application. However when I assign the response received by the COM dll from the external app. to a CComBSTR variable within the COM dll it mess up the Chinese characters. I don't know why.

Comment: You cannot assign a Big5 string as-is to a `(CCom)BSTR`, you have to decode the Big5 bytes to UTF-16, such as with `MultiByteToWideChar()`  using codepage 950, and then you can assign the result to `(CCom)BSTR`.

Comment: Issue is resolved by using _bstr_t variable instead of CComBSTR. When I assign the Response(which contains Chinese characters 個人壹) to a CComBSTR it messes it up (becomes Ó¤H³ü¡@¡@¡@¡@¡@¡@¡@¡@¡@¡@¡@¡@¡@¡@¡@¡@¡@¡@¡@¡@¡@¡@¡@¡@¡@¡@¡@¡@¡@¡@¡@¡@¡@¡@¡@¡@). However when I use _bstr_t in place of CComBSTR it is able to retain the exact Chinese character after the value is assigned to it.
Am not clear about why CComBSTR is not able to do the job? What's the difference between CComBSTR and _bstr_t?

Comment: There is virtually no difference. `CComBSTR` and `_bstr_t` are both wrappers for `BSTR` to provide automatic memory management, but `CComBSTR` offers more in the way of utility methods to operate on the `BSTR` data. But both classes support assignment of input data using either `char*` and `wchar_t*` strings. So the issue has to be in *HOW* you are assigning the Big5 string to the `CComBSTR` that is messing it up.  But since you have not yet provided *any* code showing how you are receiving the Big5 data or assigning/converting it to `BSTR`, nobody can tell you what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`MultiByteToWideChar()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072(v=vs.85).aspx) with code page `950` (for Big5).